# I have issue with CREATE TABLE and then INSERT you table

Tags: mysql

I have issue width CREATE TABLE and then INSERT you table.

This is what I want to do. CREATE TABLE LIKE and then INSERT SELECT * FROM.

I be creating multiple tables at the same time. I will be using a table like sample table to create the tables. Then editing the new tables in the future.

This Sample table.

| id | old_data | new_data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | pool_00 | pool_01 |
| 2 | pool_00 | pool_02 |

This is MySQL code I’m having issues with.

```
CREATE TABLE `new_data` LIKE `old_data`; 
INSERT `new_data` SELECT * FROM `old_data`;
```

This is the error I get.

Error
SQL query:

CREATE TABLE `new_data` LIKE `old_data`
MySQL said: Documentation

#1146 - Table 'oerpn_survivor_us.old_data' doesn't exist.

**I run this MySQL code and it works.**

```
CREATE TABLE pool_01 LIKE pool_00; 
INSERT pool_01 SELECT * FROM pool_00;

CREATE TABLE pool_02 LIKE pool_00; 
INSERT pool_02 SELECT * FROM pool_00;
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the error message verbatim:

> #1146 - Table 'oerpn_survivor_us.old_data' doesn't exist.

I would assume that the issue is that the `old_data` table exists on some database other than the one you are current using.  If so, then one fix here would be to simply scope `old_data` to the correct database.  Your code should look something like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE db2.new_data SELECT * FROM db1.old_data;
```

Here `db2` is your current database, which appears to be `oerpn_survivor_us`, and `db1` should be replaced by the name of the database which contains the `old_data` table.

Comment: I run this MySQL code and it works.

```
CREATE TABLE pool_01 LIKE pool_00; 
INSERT pool_01 SELECT * FROM pool_00;

CREATE TABLE pool_02 LIKE pool_00; 
INSERT pool_02 SELECT * FROM pool_00;
```

Comment: Great, but that's basically the original code you had, and for some reason now it is working, whereas when you posted the question 25 minutes ago, it wasn't working.